# Typescript working in VScode, but eslint emitting react/prop-types error for inferred types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, react-table

In VScode it works fine because the type can be inferred from `LeadInfo`.[image]

However, Eslint is emitting errors of `missing props validation`
[image]

By the way, the `Column` is from `React-table` and we already followed the `react-table` suggested setup from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table

Comment: Put a props validation in?

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard, thanks for the suggestion, that indeed will solve the problem. But I think eslint should not emitting error in this case as the type can be inferred from the type definition `Array<Column<LeadInfo>>`.

Comment: Even when it's no longer typescript?

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard, I don't understand what you mean by `Even when it's no longer typescript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the `react/prop-types` rule in your eslint config, it doesn’t make much sense having on if your using TS

Comment: Thanks, you are right!! I think `react/prop-types` is for JS project not TS project.